# How to extract list items using regex only?

Tags: regex

I'm working on creating a regex to extract list items from a text which looks like:

```
  Blab bla bla
  1. Extract files there.
  2. Install using rights permissions.
  3. Copy some files from binary directory located in Program files
     or you can change the location.
  4. Test the software.

  Blabla
```

I used the regex like: `(\d+)\.\s(.*)` but doesn't take also the second row from `3.`

How to achieve that ?

I want to get only

```
  1. Extract files there.
  2. Install using rights permissions.
  3. Copy some files from binary directory located in Program files
     or you can change the location.
  4. Test the software.
```

Comment: Do you want to get the entire block, or each item individually? Is the indentation always like this? And a blank line below the block?

Comment: How do you indicate that a line is part of a list and not part of `blabla`? Because there is an extra line break between a list and the following text?

Comment: entire should be fine, below there are some 3-4 space identation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `(?:\d+)\.\s(?:(.*)(?:\n {3,}(.*))?)`. This assumes that any additional lines will start with 3 or more spaces ([online demo](https://regex101.com/r/I23g5M/1)). Example in Python:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"(?:\d+)\.\s(?:(.*)(?:\n {3,}(.*))?)")
>>> p.findall(text)
[('Extract files there.', ''),
 ('Install using rights permissions.', ''),
 ('Copy some files from binary directory located in Program files',
  'or you can change the location.'),
 ('Test the software.', '')]
```